# Bogus (?) Eclipse "local variable is not used" warning

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, warnings

This is a portion of my Java code, the IDE is Eclipse. 'Lines' is an array of strings.

```
//build anchor inner text
int Count = Lines.length;
String Text = ""; //<----------Eclipse shows warning here
for (int Index=0; Index<Count; Index++) {
  Text += Lines[Index];
  if (Index<Count-1)
    Text += "<br/>";
}
```

**The 'Text' variable is declared outside the 'for' loop, however, it is used inside**.
Eclispe shows this warning to me: "**The value of the local variable Text is not used**" at the declaration line of variable 'Text'.

How could it be so? It is used inside the 'for' loop.

Comment: Side note, in Java variables should start with lower case. Only class should start with upper case.

Comment: in this project of mine, the convention is inverted :)

Comment: what if you declare the String without a value?  `String Text;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning an empty string to your variable `Text`, and then not *definitely* reading it  (at least in the snippet shown). When `Count == 0`, or even when `Count < 1`, the loop body won't get executed, and so `Text` isn't used. I presume you'll do something with `Text` later on, though?

Comment: Downvoted because this is wrong. It's not because he's not definitely reading it - it's because he's definitely not reading it. `+=` doesn't count as reading for the purpose of this warning.

Answer (score 6):

You are setting the variables value, but its value are not used in your code. The warning is harmless and will most likely go away when you make use of the variables value.

Comment: as in my code, it is used to concatencate with another string in the 'for' loop

Comment: Never say harmless, strive for 0 warning if possible.

Comment: You can also supress warnings with annotations in eclipse. Be a rebel! Kidding aside,its true that you should always strive for no warnings. My point was just that this particular one wont cause any problems.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse is most likely complaining because you are throwing stuff into your `Text` variable without ever doing anything with it. For instance, doing something such as `System.Console.WriteLine(Text);` (assuming that `Text` is a string) should remove the warning.

Comment: as in my code, it is used to concatencate with another string in the 'for' loop

Comment: @PaulDinh: Eclipse is complaining because you are *never* using the variable, so if you pass it to a method which actually *does* something with it, the warning should be removed. I simply posted a simple example to show you how can this warning be removed.

Comment: the value of it is used inside the 'for' loop to concatenate with other strings, isn't it already 'used'?

Comment: @PaulDinh: Sorry, bad choice of words. You are not doing anything with what ever value you are throwing in it, you need to *consume* the variable. Throwing it in a print statement or passing it as a method variable does that.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing to the variable `Text` but you are not reading from it - effectively meaning that you're doing computation you don't need to.

Once you return the text or display it to the console etc. it will remove the warning.

Comment: as in my code, it is used to concatencate with another string in the 'for' loop

Answer (score 0):

- when you concatenate use `StringBuilder()`
- funny to reverse convention, but dangerous (collision with class name), forgot this habit for professionnal usage or real work.
- Eclipse is kind with you : after made your `Test` bigger you forgot it? Really, you do nothing with it, you worked for nothing. Time consumption for 'null'.
- you can put `public static Test` to remove warning, and read it from all other programs.